# Magento Export Customers/Products not containing entity_id

Tags: magento

I'm using the Magento Import/Export profiles in a cron job. The exports work pretty well.
When I went through the csv files, I noticed, surprisingly, that the customer_id for customers export and product_id for products export were missing.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a Magento bug? 
The export profiles are the default ones, with no special configurations.

Thanks,
Radu

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Magento doesn't include entity_id in the exports to avoid issues that may appear when importing a csv file previously exported.

While searching for answers on this issue I discovered this article: http://learntipsandtricks.com/blog/magento/146/Magento-How-to-Export-Customer-ID-with-ImportExport-Profile

I'll be back with more details after I test every approach in the article above.

Comment: it's too bad magento doesn't have a primary key but for the entity id.  If it did use natural keys we'd not need this.  Thanks for the artical  point... it was most helpful

Answer (score 0):

When I've done a product export I noticed the same thing. It is confusing, but I don't think it is a bug. You see it in a regular repeating pattern, right? I believe the rows with empty keys are those that have the same key as the row(s) above it. If I have time I'll try to find documentation later.

Comment: What do you mean by: "I believe the rows with empty keys are those that have the same key as the row(s) above it."

Comment: On product export, if a product belongs to many categories (for instance) the product will occupy many rows in the CSV.. Row 1 will contain the bulk of the info, row 2..n will contain only the extra categories.  It's not related to your question, because the respondent refers to "keys" on fields that are not key.  Like SKU. sku is not a viable key, because some of the magento queries are case sensitive, and some are not.  so DAVE and dave might return a record you're not looking for.  Also soap calls remove spaces but the sku can have trailing spaces: "dave " cannot be found via soap.